# jquery give to image opacity and restore it after animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, opacity

I have a problem with my jquery code. I want to give an image a 50% `opacity` and animate it 720px to the left. After this animation I'm trying to restore opacity to 100%.

I have this html code:

```
 <div id="imageShow">
         <img id="img_1" src="image.jpg">      
    </div>
    <button id="button">press</button>
```

And when the button is clicked, I call this jquery code:

```
             $(function () {
                    $("#button").click(function (evt) {

                        evt.preventDefault();

                        $("#imageShow").css({ opacity: 0.5 })
                        var isfade = true

                        animateFunction().done(function () {
                            if (isfade) {
                                $("#imageShow").css("opacity", "");
                             }

                        //im trying it both ways but nothing happend after animation                   
                        $("#imageShow").css("opacity", "");

                  });



            function animateFunction() {
                return $('#imageShow').animate({ left: '720px' }, 1000);
            }
```

Everything works fine except opacity to 100% and i can't understand why.
Thanks for the help :D

Comment: you never set it back to 1.0?

Comment: i have tried it , and with many other ways

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues.

1) To set the opacity to 100%, use '1' instead of ' '.

2) The simpler way to execute something after a jQuery animation is finished is to inject it as a callback function as in the code below.

3) Your code does not close properly in a couple of places. When you write something like `(function() {` you have to remember to close it off with `})` for proper syntax: `(function() {...})`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#imageShow').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $('#imageShow').css({ opacity: 0.5 });
            var isfade = true;
            $('#imageShow').animate({ left: '720px' }, 1000, function() {
                if (isfade) {
                    $('#imageShow').css({ opacity: 1.0 });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is a JFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/szq4s172/1/

Comment: this code isnt work eather. Make image fade and then animate it but when image finish the animation move doesent turn into opacity 1

Comment: Sorry, if you copied my code verbatim there was a typo. I fixed it. Also, if you want to fade, try calling `animate()` on the opacity instead of `css()`.